# Selenoid: How to setup hostname for chromium driver in browser.json

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenoid

I run a selenoid with docker-compose, I cannot setup a host table for browsers, because "hosts" attribute seems to be ignored in the browser started from selenoid. I cannot open the http://myfrontend page because it cannot resolve hostname.

A have a following `browsers.json` configuration:

```
{
  "chrome": {
    "default": "latest",
    "versions": {
      "latest": {
        "image": "selenoid/vnc_chrome:94.0",
        "port": "4444",
        "tmpfs": {"/tmp":"size=512m"},
        "env" : [ "DRIVER_ARGS=--disable-web-security --ignore-certificate-errors --verbose" ],
        "hosts": [
          "myfrontend:172.20.176.10"
        ]
      },
      "94.0": {
        "image": "selenoid/vnc_chrome:94.0",
        "port": "4444",
        "tmpfs": {"/tmp":"size=512m"},
        "env" : [ "DRIVER_ARGS=--disable-web-security --ignore-certificate-errors --verbose" ],
        "hosts": [
          "myfrontend:172.20.176.10"
        ]
      }     
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend running everything in custom Docker network instead of `bridge`. In that case you simply don't need to use `hosts` because in custom Docker network containers can be accessed by name (Docker automatically manages DNS). How to configure Selenoid in custom network is shown here: https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/#_option_2_running_selenoid_in_custom_docker_network

Comment: I would like to access an external service (not in my DNS and not in my computer)